# Split multiple variadic template packs based on function pointer arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create some template based function to pack a function pointer and some input arguments and later call it and store some output values in some other place. As a start I'm trying to create a function with one variadic template for the input arguments and one for the return values. This is what I came up with, but it doesn't work:

```
template<typename... Args, typename... Ret>
void Call(void (*func)(Args..., Ret...), Args&&... args)
{

}

void Foo(float x, int& y)
{
    y = int(x * x);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Call(&Foo, 2.f);
    return 1;
}
```

[ideon](http://ideone.com/ThD4ak) gives me the following error:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
prog.cpp:16:16: error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(float, int&)' to 'void (*)(float, float, int&)' [-fpermissive]
  Call(&Foo, 2.f);
                ^
prog.cpp:4:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void Call(void (*)(Args ..., Ret ...), Args&& ...) [with Args = {float}; Ret = {float, int&}]'
 void Call(void (*func)(Args..., Ret...), Args&&... args)
      ^
```

Why is `Ret` deduced to `{float, int&}`? The function pointer argument is obviously used in the deduction, but it seems like `Args...` is not used.

Comment: What are you expecting `Ret` to be? Is it meant to be the return value?

Comment: In this example I would expect `Ret` to be `{int&}` and `Args` to be `{float}`. `Args` because of the trailing arguments to `Call` and `Ret` because that's what left in the function pointer arguments. But maybe that's too good to be true?

Comment: `std::tuple<Ret...> (*func)(Args...)` would be easier to work with..

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, but I'd prefer to have input arguments followed by return arguments to keep consistency with the rest of the code.

Comment: I strongly suggest switching to returning a `std::tuple` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a layer to fix some template parameters:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
struct helper
{
    template <typename ...Ret, typename ... Us>
    static void Call(void (*func)(Ts..., Ret...), Us&&... args)
    {

    }

};


template<typename F, typename... Args>
void Call(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    helper<Args...>::Call(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b1f2dca82d6ae3c)